# Using `pip freeze > requirements` in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I found how to use pip command in code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["pip", "freeze"])
```

It displays all packages in command prompt.

But it doesn't work this way:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["pip", "freeze", ">", "requirements.txt"])
```

It doesn't writes it to file, it prints in console again.

**How to run this command in the right way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirection is implemented in the shell/terminal, that means the command must be executed in the shell using `shell=True` keyword argument. Otherwise subprocess executes the first item in the list and uses the rest as arguments to it. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for subprocess for more information.

```
subprocess.call("pip freeze > requirements.txt", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
>>> with open('requirements.txt', 'w') as file_:
...   subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=file_).communicate()
...
```

or, `call` if you prefer that

```
>>> with open('requirements.txt', 'w') as file_:
    ...   subprocess.call(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=file_)
```

Comment: If you used wait rather than communicate, it would be the same as using call.

Comment: @DanD. I did not understand this. Can you elaborate more on this comment?

Comment: I mean `Popen(cmd).wait()` is the same as `call(cmd)`.